# Creating tables in a MS Word file using Java

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to create a table in a Microsoft Office Word file using Java. Can anybody tell me how to do it with an example?

Comment: Why is this community wiki? This seems more like a 'regular' question.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

> The POI project is the master project
>   for developing pure Java ports of file
>   formats based on Microsoft's OLE 2
>   Compound Document Format. OLE 2
>   Compound Document Format is used by
>   Microsoft Office Documents, as well as
>   by programs using MFC property sets to
>   serialize their document objects.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen it done, and I work in Word a lot.  If you really want to programatically do something in a word document then I'd advise using Microsoft's scripting language VBA which is specifically designed for this purpose.  In fact, I'm working in it right now.

If you're working under Open Office then they have a very similar set of macro-powered tools for doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Office 2003 has an xml format, and the default document format for office 2007 is xml (zipped). So you could just generate xml from java. If you open an existing document it's not too hard too see the xml required.

Alternatively, you could use openoffice's api to generate a document, and save it as a ms-word document.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet can be used to create a table dynamically in MS Word document.

```
WPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable tableTwo = document.createTable();
XWPFTableRow tableTwoRowOne = tableTwo.getRow(0);
tableTwoRowOne.getCell(0).setText(Knode1);
tableTwoRowOne.createCell().setText(tags.get("node1").toString());
for (int i = 1; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
    String node = "node";
    String nodeVal = "";
    XWPFTableRow tr = null;
    node = node + (i + 1);
    nodeVal = tags.get(node).toString();
    if (tr == null) {
        tr = tableTwo.createRow();
        tr.getCell(0).setText(nodeList[i]);
        tr.getCell(1).setText(tags.get(node).toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Our feature set is to hit a button in our web app and get the page you are looking at back as a Word document.  We use the docx schema for description of documents and have a bunch of Java code on the server side which does the document creation and response back to our web client.  The formatting itself is done with some compiled xsl-t's from within Java to translate from our own XML persistence tier.

The docx schema is pretty hard to understand.  The way we made most progress was to create template docx's in Word with exactly the formatting that we needed but with bogus content.  We then fooled around with them until we understood exactly what was going on.  There is a huge amount in the docx that you don't really need to worry about.  When reading / translating the docx Word is pretty tolerant to a partially complete formatting schema.  In fact we chose to strip out pretty much all the formatting because it also means that the user's default formatting takes precedence, which they seem to prefer.  It also makes the xsl process faster and the resulting document smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**I manage the docx4j project**

docx4j contains a class [TblFactory](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/table/TblFactory.java), which creates regular tables (ie no row or column spans), with the default settings which Word 2007 would create, and with the dimensions specified by the user.

If you want a more complex table, the easiest approach is to create it in Word, then copy the resulting XML into a String in your IDE, where you can use docx4j's XmlUtils.unmarshalString to create a Tbl object from it.

Answer (score 0):

Using my little zip utility, you can create docx with ease, if you know what you're doing. Word's DOCX file format is simply zip (folders with xml files). By using java zip utilities, you can modify existing docx, just the content part.

For the following sample to work, simply open Word, enter few lines, save document. Then with zip program, remove file word/document.xml (this is file where main content of the Word document is residing) from the zip. Now you have the template prepared. Save modified zip.

Here is what creation of new Word file looks:

```
/* docx file head  */
    final String DOCUMENT_XML_HEAD =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>" +
            "<w:document xmlns:wpc=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas\" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:wp14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:w10=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:w14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml\" xmlns:w15=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml\" xmlns:wpg=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup\" xmlns:wpi=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk\" xmlns:wne=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml\" xmlns:wps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape\" mc:Ignorable=\"w14 w15 wp14\">" +
            "<w:body>";

    /* docx file foot  */
    final String DOCUMENT_XML_FOOT =
             "</w:body>" +
             "</w:document>";


    final ZipOutputStream zos =  new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\TEMP\\test.docx"));

    final String fullDocumentXmlContent = DOCUMENT_XML_HEAD + "<w:p><w:r><w:t>Hey MS Word, hello from java.</w:t></w:r></w:p>" + DOCUMENT_XML_FOOT;

    final si.gustinmi.DocxZipCreator creator = new si.gustinmi.DocxZipCreator();

    // create new docx file
    creator.createDocxFromExistingDocx(zos, "c:\\TEMP\\existingDocx.docx", fullDocumentXmlContent);
```

These are zip utilities:

```
package si.gustinmi;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

/**
 * Creates new docx from existing one.
 * @author gustinmi [at] gmail [dot] com
 */
public class DocxZipCreator {

    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DocxZipCreator.class.getCanonicalName());

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;


    /** OnTheFly zip creator. Traverses through existing docx zip and creates new one simultaneousl.
     * On the end, custom document.xml is inserted inside
     * @param zipFilePath location of existing docx template (without word/document.xml)
     * @param documentXmlContent content of the word/document.xml
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void createDocxFromExistingDocx(ZipOutputStream zos, String zipFilePath, String documentXmlContent) throws IOException {

        final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(zipFilePath);
        final ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(fis);

        try{
            log.info("Starting to create new docx zip");
            ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            while (entry != null) { // iterates over entries in the zip file
                copyEntryfromZipToZip(zipIn, zos, entry.getName());
                zipIn.closeEntry();
                entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
            }

            // add document.xml to existing zip
            addZipEntry(documentXmlContent, zos, "word/document.xml");

        }finally{
            zipIn.close();
            zos.close();
            log.info("End of docx creation");
        }

    }

    /** Copies sin gle entry from zip to zip  */
    public void copyEntryfromZipToZip(ZipInputStream is, ZipOutputStream zos, String entryName)
    {
        final byte [] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
        int len; 
        int lenTotal = 0;
        try {

            final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName); 
            zos.putNextEntry(entry); 

            final CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32(); 
            while ((len = is.read(data)) > -1){ 
                zos.write(data, 0, len); 
                crc32.update(data, 0, len);
                lenTotal += len;
            } 

            entry.setSize(lenTotal); 
            entry.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
            entry.setCrc(crc32.getValue());

        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try { zos.closeEntry();} catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    /**  Create new zip entry with content
     * @param content content of a new zip entry
     * @param zos 
     * @param entryName name (npr: word/document.xml)
     */
    public void addZipEntry(String content, ZipOutputStream zos, String entryName)
    {
        final byte [] data = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
        int len; 
        int lenTotal = 0;
        try {

            final InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName); 
            zos.putNextEntry(entry); 

            final CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32(); 
            while ((len = is.read(data)) > -1){ 
                zos.write(data, 0, len); 
                crc32.update(data, 0, len);
                lenTotal += len;
            } 

            entry.setSize(lenTotal); 
            entry.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
            entry.setCrc(crc32.getValue());

        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try { zos.closeEntry();} catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not working. First File not opening says it is corrupt and second file is empty.

Comment: How did you create zip file. It has to be without any root folder, etc. Best way on Windows is to use TotalCMD zipping support. Proposed order: 1. Create docx in MSWord. Open zip in TotalCMD with CTRL + PgDown. Remove document.xml. Press backspace and confirm zip changes.

Comment: I think i was doing separate task which is did using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17835814/1459174

Answer (score -1):

[Office Writer](http://officewriter.softartisans.com/officewriter-240.aspx) would be a better tool to use than POI for your requirement.

If all you want is a simple table without too much of formatting, I would use this simple trick. Use Java to generate the table as HTML using plain old table,tr,td tags and copy the rendered HTML table into the word document ;)

Comment: URL no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

Click here for a [Working example with source code](http://dinoch.dyndns.org:7070/WordML/AboutWordML.jsp).
This example generates MS-Word docs from Java, based on a template concept.